# SKPhysicsBody Path Generator

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I'm using [SKPhysicsBody Path Generator](http://insyncapp.net/SKPhysicsBodyPathGenerator.html)

to generate polygonFromPath to my sprite. The problem is I need a path with two holes end how can I achieve it?

As shown in the image below the path must be connected with at most one hole but I need two holes! Any help?

[image]

I also tried the following but it crash:

```
let path = CGPathCreateMutable()

        MoveToPoint(path, x: 51 , y:22 , node:sprite)
        AddLineToPoint(path, x: 38 , y:45 , node:sprite)
        AddLineToPoint(path, x: 32 , y:44 , node:sprite)
        AddLineToPoint(path, x: 32 , y:0 , node:sprite)
        AddLineToPoint(path, x: 39 , y:0 , node:sprite)

        let path2 = CGPathCreateMutable()

        MoveToPoint(path2, x: 0 , y:22 , node:sprite)
        AddLineToPoint(path2, x: 13 , y:0 , node:sprite)
        AddLineToPoint(path2, x: 19 , y:0 , node:sprite)
        AddLineToPoint(path2, x: 19 , y:45 , node:sprite)
        AddLineToPoint(path2, x: 13 , y:45 , node:sprite)

sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(bodies: [path, path2])
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `bodyWithPolygonFromPath` for a shape like you want. `bodyWithPolygonFromPath` only works with a convex polygonal path.

You can use `bodyWithBodies:(NSArray *)bodies` to draw the 2 triangles on the right and bottom side, and the square for the top left. Just remember that the empty space will not register a contact.

Here is an example:

```
SKSpriteNode node0 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor lightGrayColor] size:CGSizeMake(200, 200)];
node0.position = CGPointMake(400, 400);

SKPhysicsBody *firstBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(50, 50) center:CGPointMake(-75, 75)];
SKPhysicsBody *secondBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(200, 50) center:CGPointMake(0, -75)];
SKPhysicsBody *thirdBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(50, 150) center:CGPointMake(75, 26)];
node0.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithBodies:@[firstBody, secondBody, thirdBody]];
node0.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
[self addChild:node0];
```

Comment: Thanks for your response :) I edit my question: I tried SKPhysicsBody(bodies: [path, path2]) but the app crash. Any help?

Comment: A path is not a body. You need to create 2 bodies and then use them to create the third body.

Comment: @Fogmeister As written in the documentation it's an array of AnyObject: init(bodies bodies: [AnyObject]) -> SKPhysicsBody So I can't add path as array element?

Comment: @Fogmeister Ok I read more then I got it: bodies
An array of SKPhysicsBody objects. Thanks

Comment: @sangony THANKS I solved it please check my answer please if you have any feedback on my answer feel free to tell me I will be glad to improve my code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I sovled it :)

let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "cell3")

```
sprite.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

let path = CGPathCreateMutable()

MoveToPoint(path, x: 51 , y:22 , node:sprite)
AddLineToPoint(path, x: 38 , y:45 , node:sprite)
AddLineToPoint(path, x: 32 , y:44 , node:sprite)
AddLineToPoint(path, x: 32 , y:0 , node:sprite)
AddLineToPoint(path, x: 39 , y:0 , node:sprite)

CGPathCloseSubpath(path)

let path2 = CGPathCreateMutable()

MoveToPoint(path2, x: 0 , y:22 , node:sprite)
AddLineToPoint(path2, x: 13 , y:0 , node:sprite)
AddLineToPoint(path2, x: 19 , y:0 , node:sprite)
AddLineToPoint(path2, x: 19 , y:45 , node:sprite)
AddLineToPoint(path2, x: 13 , y:45 , node:sprite)

CGPathCloseSubpath(path2)

let b1 = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFromPath: path)

let b2 = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFromPath: path2)

sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(bodies: [b1, b2])
```